# How to define a Persistent table without a primary key?

Tags: database, haskell, persistent

I am developing a feature working with a time series table in Postgres (TimescaleDB). There is no primary key in such table.
I guess Persistent library supports such case.
Persistent TH generates ID column if the primary key is not defined obviously.

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Monitoring
    device Int
    value  Int
    created Timestamp
    deriving Show
```

Comment: Normally in that case, all fields are part of the primary key (both at the database side and in Persist).

Comment: then just auto gen id is better because insert speed is holy cow.